# PHP WordPress theme if/else falling through

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was working on a header that could be used universally for my site.  Unfortunately, this also includes a lot of conditional checking for WordPress functions, so that I end up with the correct data for headings.  I have a piece of code that checks to see if the function that provides a title for WordPress pages exists.  If it does, it then checks to see if that function returns anything.  If it doesn't, it prints a default title.  Otherwise, it prints the title and appends a standard title to it.  My problem is that it seems to print the title, and then appends the default title.  So instead of printing: "pageTitle-append" it prints "pageTitleStandardTitle-append".  Here's my code:

```
if(function_exists('wp_title')):
    if(wp_title()):
        wp_title();
        echo ' - Standard Appended Title';
    else:
        echo 'Blog - Standard Appended Title';
    endif;
else:
    echo $title.' - Standard Appended Title';
endif;
```

Comment: u call to this function twice wp_title(), in the if and line after

Comment: I know I call it twice: once to see if it returns anything, and once to actually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
if(function_exists('wp_title')) {

    $wp_title = wp_title(false,false,false);

    if($wp_title) {

        echo $wp_title;

    } else {

        echo 'Blog';
    }

} else {

    echo $title;

}

echo ' - Standard Appended Title';
```

Comment: Setting `false` in `wp_title()`, stops it from being echoed.